# Talend Using Custom SQL Template

Tags: sql, talend, elt

So i would like to use the tSqlTemplate componente to delete all entries from a MySql database table. Should be simple enough:

[image]

here is the what the template looks like:

[image]

however i can't do anything with it, since i am unable to select it:

[image]

as you can see, the button "Hinzufügen" (meaning "add") is greyed out, meaning i cant add anything there. Then what is the use of the component?

For unidentified reasons it just started to work. Additionally a ';' was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unidentified reasons it just started to work. Additionally a ';' was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use `tSQLTemplate`?

It seems like you could just use `tDBRow` and execute your deletion query there.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly right, tbh I was not aware of this component. But it was for educational purposes.